# Implicit function theorem in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, implicit-function-theorem, tangent-line

Let $F(x,y)$ be a $C^2$-function defined on a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)\in \Bbb R^2$. Suppose that $F(x_0,y_0)=0, F_y(x_0,y_0)\ne0$. By [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem), the equation $F(x,y)=0$ defines a $C^2$-curve $C:y=f(x)$ on a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$. My questions are as follows:

> (1) Show that the tangent line to $C$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ is parallel to $x$-axis if and only if $F_x(x_0,y_0)=0$.
>
> (2) Under the assumption of (1), show that if $F_y(x_0,y_0)F_{xx}(x_0,y_0)<0$ then there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $C \cap U \subset \{(x_0,y_0)\in \Bbb R^2\mid y \ge y_0\}$.

Firstly, I know the following formulae:
$y'=f'(x)=-\frac{F_x}{F_y}$ and $y''=-\frac{F_{xx}F_y^2-2F_{xy}F_{x}F_{y}+F_{yy}F_x^2}{F_y^3}$. For (1), the tangent line to $C$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ is parallel to $x$-axis $\iff y'(x_0,y_0)=0 \iff F_x(x_0,y_0)=0$. I guess the formula of $y''$ will play some role in the proof of (2) but I can't figure it out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint to get you started:

In the formula for $y''(x_0)$, you have $F_x=0$, which leaves only the factors $F_{xx}$ and $F_y$. This should be enough for you to determine the sign of $y''(x_0)$, and because of continuity it will keep that sign in a neighbourhood of $x_0$ too.

Comment: Are you using the second derivative test? It states that if $y'(x_0)=0$ and $y''(x_0)>0$ then $y$ has a local minimum at $x = x_0$. Thus there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $C \cap U \subset \{(x_0,y_0)\in \Bbb R^2\mid y \ge y_0\}$.

Comment: Well, what I was thinking was that if we use continuity of $y''$ to show that $y''>0$ in a neighbourhood of $x_0$, then $y$ is convex in that neighbourhood, and thus we have a local minimum. But I realize now that this is an unnecessary detour. Just as you write, one can conclude that it's a local minimum simply from the fact that $y''(x_0)$ exists and is positive.

Comment: I was asked to examine whether the converse of part (2) is correct? I think it is not but cannot find a counter-example. Would you mind helping me on this additional question?

Comment: $y-x^4=0$ perhaps?

Comment: What is your $(x_0,y_0)$?

Comment: I thought I would leave that for you to figure out! (Where's the local minimum?)

Comment: That is the origin! One can see that $F_{xx}(0,0)=0$.

Comment: There you have it!